# I checkmark the Auto Smooth option under Object Data > Normals > Auto Smooth, and the normals are all messed up. Can anyone help?

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

I import a mesh that I downloaded online, and it's got Auto Smooth enabled already.
However, the normals are all janky, and are undesireable.

Below is two captures of the Normals I'm talking about.[image]
[image: AutoSmooth Capture1]

I've also taken a picture of the funky lines that come out of the Vertices of the mesh here:[image]

How do I smooth my mesh without this crappy looking Normal?

Comment: Maybe try to clear the custom split normals data in the Object Data panel > Geometry Data

Answer (score 0):

The object probably has corrupted custom split normals.
To clear those go Object data properties->geometry data->clear custom split normals data.

Comment: I've tried that method before, but it just screws up the Auto Smooth, reverting it to it's chunky polygonal shape.

Comment: Could you please send a picture with the auto smooth "chunky polygonal shape".